# My jQuery snippet recognize the manual input but not the onClick input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sum up the fields of my form. If I insert the value manually, it's working. But when I add the values clicking on the buttons, it doesn't. I believe I should change something in the jQuery part, but I don't know what. Does anyone have an idea?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('form#lines-form-1 :input').change(function() {
  var tot = 0;
  $("form#lines-form-1 :input").each(function() {
    tot += Number($(this).val());    
  });
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
</script>

<script>
   function changeValueA(x){
     document.getElementById('i1').value=x.innerHTML;
    }
    function changeValueB(x){
     document.getElementById('i2').value=x.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <text>Field A</text>
    <button id="80" onclick="changeValueA(this)">80</button>
    <button id="50" onclick="changeValueA(this)">50</button>
</div>

<div>
    <text>Field B</text>
    <button id="80" onclick="changeValueB(this)">80</button>
    <button id="50" onclick="changeValueB(this)">50</button>
</div>


<form id="lines-form-1">
  <label>Field A</label>
  <input type="text" id="i1" name="i1">
  <br>
  <label>Field B</label>
  <input type="text" id="i2" name="i2">
  <br>
</form>

<div id="tot-qty">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because manually changing the value of an `input` through code does not raise any events. Therefore the `change` event listener you've created to update the total never fires. To fix this you can manually `trigger()` the event after updating the value.

Also note that it's good practice to use unobtruisve event handlers instead of inline ones. As you've already included jQuery in the page you may as well stick with that. Try this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let value = this.value;
  $($(this).data('target')).val(value).trigger('input');
});

$('.field').on('input', function() {
  let tot = 0;
  $("form#lines-form-1 :input").each((i, el) => tot += parseInt(el.value || 0, 10));
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <text>Field A</text>
  <button type="button" id="80" data-target="#i1" value="80">80</button>
  <button type="button" id="50" data-target="#i1" value="50">50</button>
</div>

<div>
  <text>Field B</text>
  <button type="button" id="80" data-target="#i2" value="80">80</button>
  <button type="button" id="50" data-target="#i2" value="50">50</button>
</div>


<form id="lines-form-1">
  <label>Field A</label>
  <input type="text" class="field" id="i1" name="i1"><br>

  <label>Field B</label>
  <input type="text" class="field" id="i2" name="i2"><br>
</form>

<div id="tot-qty">0</div>
```